# Boost Circular Buffer, how to make it call some function when it is filled?

Tags: c++, events, boost, event-handling, circular-buffer

I like [Boost Templated Circular Buffer Container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html), but how to get when it was filled 100%?

```
   #include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>

   int main() {

      // Create a circular buffer with a capacity for 3 integers.
      boost::circular_buffer<int> cb(3);

      // Insert some elements into the buffer.
      cb.push_back(1);
      cb.push_back(2);
      cb.push_back(3);

      // Here I want some function to be called (for example one that would cout all buffer contents)

      int a = cb[0];  // a == 1
      int b = cb[1];  // b == 2
      int c = cb[2];  // c == 3

      return 0;
   }
```

So how to listen for such event in `boost::circular_buffer` and for example cout all buffer contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the `circular_buffer` instance into its own class and implement event handling on top of it.

```
class MyCircularBuffer
{
public:
    MyCircularBuffer() : buffer(3) {}

    void PushBack(int i)
    {
        buffer.push_back(i);
        if(buffer.size() == 3)
        {
            // buffer is full!
        }
    }
private:
    boost::circular_buffer<int> buffer;
};
```

If code outside of `MyCircularBuffer` needs to be notified of the event, you can implement some variant of the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), use [Boost.Function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/function.html) or use some other callback mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't fire an event. You must manually check to see if it is full each time you add to it, and if it is, then you execute some process.

This would typically be done by wrapping the container in a user-created object, so that you can monitor additions to the buffer.

Or, to put it another way, you don't need a generic solution; just write an object that uses the container and flushes it automatically.